# Need help regarding my thesis project related to Data Analysis

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset, linear-regression, visualization

I am working on a project with a company that manufactures Injection molding machines. I am to perform data analysis on some selected parameters as a part of my thesis to tell the company if from these parameters some ideas can be generated to suggest any changes in the health of the machine.

I have used Pandas for data cleaning and plotted the graphs using Matplotlib. I collected the data daily from the machine for two different input materials and have a dataset for each material for 13 days. Now the problem I am facing is how to analyze the data.

Sure I can plot various kinds of plot, bar plots, scatter plots, histograms, box-plots in matplotlib, but since, I am writing my Master's thesis, I am unsure if just plotting and discussing the data would suffice my degree without any mathematical calculations?

Another idea I got from my Math Prof was to use DOE, but I don't seem to understand what and how I could use DOE in my case. I was thinking to apply a regression model from scikit-learn and maybe tell the company during my presentation about the possibility of some changes in the future in some of the monitored parameters.

So far, I have seen no significant changes in the values. Or am I missing something? Or am I doing the analysis in the wrong direction? I am really confused. I am new to this field. Any suggestions and help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thats why supervisor is there to ask him this questions, we can speculate given that we dont know  a lot of details (dataset, what are you studying etc...)